# IWD ap not starting: START_AP failed: -95

Tags: wifi, driver, daemon, netlink, wpa-supplicant

Interface is set to AP mode.

When turning on ap it is giving "Operation not supported".

[iwd]# ap wlan0 start "start_wpa2" password
Operation not supported

Output of iwd -d:

```
src/netdev.c:netdev_link_notify() event 16 on ifindex 5
src/scan.c:scan_notify() Scan notification Trigger Scan(33)
src/scan.c:scan_notify() Scan notification New Scan Results(34)
src/netdev.c:netdev_link_notify() event 16 on ifindex 5
Could not register frame watch type 0000: -22
Could not register frame watch type 0020: -22
Could not register frame watch type 00a0: -22
Could not register frame watch type 00c0: -22
START_AP failed: -95
```

Using WPA_Supplicant, same AP is able to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a different device driver solves the problem, it is problem in the driver, not in IWD. By adding debug prints in cfg80211 and Netlink helps which is making problem.

Comment: It would probably be just a bit more helpful to other if you could elaborate what the different driver is, and what version the previous one was.